# Question: Mining Rewards and Uncle Rates

Tags: ether, mining, etherscan

Looking at https://etherscan.io/chart/uncles we can see that uncle rates are on the rise lately. Recently every day more than 3000 ETH is awarded in uncle rewards. How does this situation affect mining rewards? Lets assume that miner gets all the rewards i.e transactions + 3 ETH block reward + uncle rewards. As I understand high uncle rates should increase miner rewards (more ETH is granted to miner from the network, hence larger average block reward), however, http://whattomine.com/coins/151-eth-ethash states that current reward is 2.91 ETH, on which they comment "Reduced due to uncles lowered reward". Where is the truth? Are miners getting more or less than 3 ETH block reward due to uncles? When uncles percentage rises do mining rewards rise or fall with it?